# Oracle Database 18c EX без объяснения причин откатывает установку

Tags: oracle, установка

Win 10 pro x64, установка Oracle Database 18c EX доходит почти до конца, в определённый момент запускается откат изменений и, без вывода какой-либо ошибки, завершает установку, что с этим можно сделать? Столкнулась с таким впервые, надеюсь на помощь.

[image: откат действий]

[image: завершение установки]

Comment: Посмотрите в логи установки: %Program Files%\Oracle\Inventory\logs, устраните ошибки, запусите снова.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

была такая ситуация, когда устанавливал oracle прямо на диск F:\
попробуйте создать папку и установить в нее

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло (никогда бы не подумала, что проблема в папке), до этого перебрала много вариантов